How to configure MongoDB for Liquibase using bean configuration?
Currently to configure MongoDB in my Liquibase project. I am using
"liquibase.properties" file.
But I want to configure it using this method. How I can achieve this?
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(){
     SpringLiquibase liquibase= new SpringLiquibase();
          //to do----------------
      return liquibase;
    }
}

